# tensorflow cannot find GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I had install "tensorflow-GPU", CUDA 10.0. and my GPU is GTX1660 ti.
I also tested bu CUDA 10.2 and 11. I added cudnn to windows PATH but I still got this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Electrical And Programming office\6_AI\RL\5_Pong_DQN\pong_DGN.py", line 38, in <module>
    gpu = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```py
>>> print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. the problem was versions of CUDA and cudnn.

[image]